# Closing the buffered reader gives error in Online judge .

Tags: java

Closing the buffered reader in the following program gives a runtime error in the online judge [codechef](http://www.codechef.com/problems/TEST) . The problem gets solved on removing the statement that closes the buffered reader .  Should I refrain from closing the buffered reader or is it just an issue with the online judge ?

```
import java.util.* ; 
import java.io.* ; 
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[])throws java.lang.Exception{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while(true){
            int num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine()) ; 
            if(num == 42){
                break ;
            }
            System.out.println(num) ;
        }
        br.close() ; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably **report this to codechef**.

IMHO you should be allowed to close stdin in this particular situation. It's unusual to close stdin, but you should be allowed to.

I figure this is actually a problem on their side: their runner probably continues to feed data into your app, and when you close the stream it fails without realizing that you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other solutions close System.in, so I guess it's not expected.